# Installed gems looking in the wrong path (Travis build)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, travis-ci

I'm having a continuing issue with OSX Travis builds.  The current issue is that it can't run gems that are installed due to this error, which obviously it's looking in the wrong place since it should be 2.1.10:

```
Could not find 'sass' (>= 0.a) among 298 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=/Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648:/Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648@global', execute `gem env` for more information
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:324:in `to_spec'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p648/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:64:in `gem'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.10/bin/sass-convert:25:in `<main>'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/travis/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p648/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I've output everything I could think of to help debug, but not sure what to look for anymore. Any thoughts? Edit: sorry, thought the links would go directly to the lines, looks like they don't. Still fairly easy to find, they're all grouped up starting at line 2623.

PATH: https://travis-ci.org/szeck87/atom-beautify/jobs/290674283#L2623

gem env: https://travis-ci.org/szeck87/atom-beautify/jobs/290674283#L2624-L2665

GEM_PATH: https://travis-ci.org/szeck87/atom-beautify/jobs/290674283#L2666-L2667

rvm info: https://travis-ci.org/szeck87/atom-beautify/jobs/290674283#L2668-L2715

which ruby: https://travis-ci.org/szeck87/atom-beautify/jobs/290674283#L2716-L2717

which gem: https://travis-ci.org/szeck87/atom-beautify/jobs/290674283#L2718-L2719

gem list: https://travis-ci.org/szeck87/atom-beautify/jobs/290674283#L2720-L2874

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the Travis environment variable, `TRAVIS_COMMIT_MESSAGE`. When you merge a PR on GitHub, the default commit message has a "message" and a "description", separated by a line break. Having that line break in the `TRAVIS_COMMIT_MESSAGE` caused path issues with Ruby and/or Rubygems.

This was resolved by blanking out the environment variable by adding the below to our .travis.yml in the before_install step at the very beginning:

`- export TRAVIS_COMMIT_MESSAGE=""`